# Attempt to root AVD running Android 4.4/5.1 is failing

Tags: root-access, windows, android-emulator

**I have referred to various posts but I don't think they seem to work, at all, whatsoever, when it comes to AVDs with Android 4.4 or 5.1.**

I felt a need to post this.

So before posting this question, I have understood a basic need for rooting AVDs or even any device.

- Mount /system in rw mode.
- Push su binary; optionally busybox binary.
- do chmod to them, say, 6755. *That should be it*.

I followed posts and successfully rooted AVD with Android 2.2, however, I tried to repeat the same thing for Android 4.4 or 5.1 (both with SELinux disabled), but it seems that there is some kind of **fallback mechanism**.

*For Android 4.4 and 5.1, /system **will be** mounted in rw mode, **but**, as soon as I try to push binaries, it gets **reverted back** to ro mode. Furthermore, it won't get back to rw mode as well, at least **until I do a reboot**. I keep getting a **permission denied** error.*

Since these worked for Android 2.2 (with a modification in filesystem type and mountpoint), I intend to execute following commands (for Android 4.4 and 5.1):

```
adb root
adb shell /system/bin/mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/vda /system
adb push su /system/xbin/su
adb shell chmod 06755 /system
adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
```

Anyone who has managed to root AVDs running these versions of Android are requested to help me in this.

**I have experience with Android Studio & Windows.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested and found that irrespective of the version of Android, if the **ABI** is **arm, armeabi or maybe even mips (not sure)**, the process of rooting is going to work. They didn't worked for me, as of now, if the **ABI** is **x86 or x86_x64** for *Android 4 and 4+*.

*Below, anything after "#" is supposed to be a helpful comment.*

**Testing working on - Android 1.x, 2.x, 3.x, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 (add additional space in subsequent boot)**:

```
adb shell mount
# Preferred command: adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system
adb push su /system/xbin/su
# Appropriate su binary from Chainfire's SuperSu.zip package.
adb shell chmod 06755 /system
adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
adb install "Super user.apk"
# Update the su binary for sure.
#adb install "Rootchecker app OR Terminal Emulator app to test."
```

**Testing working on - Android 4.3-4.4 (add additional space in subsequent boot), 5.1, 6.0**:

```
adb shell df
# See the available space in /system
adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system
adb push su /system/bin/su
adb shell chmod 0755 /system/bin/su
adb push su /system/xbin/su
adb shell chmod 0755 /system/xbin/su
adb shell su --install
adb shell "su --daemon&"
adb shell setenforce 0
# optional and recommended; adb shell mount -o remount,ro /system
adb install "Super user app"
# Update the su binary.
#adb install "Rootchecker app OR Terminal Emulator app to test."
```

Comment: You know that x86 and ARM require *different* binaries, right? There's no way a binary compiled for ARM would work on android-x86.