# How to root an Android emulator

Tags: root-access, android-emulator

My application required to use some system command such as wm size and wm size reset to change the screen size so an application supposed be running on Portrait only mode will be displayed as portrait in a landscape screen.

I have gone through many of the answer in stack overflow but still can't get an idea of how to do it.

Somebody can give me a step by step guide how to achieve this thanks. I've tried the Andydroid emulator but still not work.

I know the emulator is rooted when using adb console but looks like if I test it with my program, it was not.

Comment: You've already received the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907886/android-is-android-emulator-already-rooted/40908798#40908798).

Comment: I should remove one of the question later.. He talked about "You still need to manually elevate your privileges (by using su)". How do I manually elevate the privilege

Comment: _"How do I manually elevate the privilege"_ There is a couple of thousands of questions about it on SO with tons of great answers. Do you ask us how to Google?

Comment: I have  gone through in google to see how to root but none of them work... I understand we can find good answer in google, maybe i am not smart enough to extinguish which are the good answer. I tried to follow this but it doesn't seem to work : http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2015/11/12/howto-root-andyos-under-mac-os-x/comment-page-1/#comment-91938

Comment: What exactly is your emulator? Genymotion and AMIDuOS can be (relatively easily) rooted.

Comment: I went to Genymotion but seems like it require to pay to use. Tried the Andydroid, but the version installed is below my minSDKVersion of my application. Currently, I am running the emulator from AVD manager with current spec. AVD for Nexus One running 480*800mdpi with API 21 android 5.0.2 x86.

Comment: where to get the up-to-date su binary.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to root. **Only work on certain API Level stated in their answer**.

[Attempt to root AVD running Android 4.4/5.1 is failing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148841/attempt-to-root-avd-running-android-4-4-5-1-is-failing)